# wxTextEntryDialog with Tabs

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there a way to allow wxTextEntryDialogs to accept the tab character? I'm using wxPython and would like to accept tabs so that I can ask the user for the delimiter used in a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to paste it in, but this is obviously not user friendly. I'd use a custom dialog with the predefined choices (e.g. radio buttons) for TAB, comma, semicolon etc and a text control for a custom separator entry.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that but was hoping I might have overlooked some method to just allow tabs in a text box of some sort. Thanks for your thoughts though. I may end up going that route.

Comment: For anyone who runs into this in the future, the relevant style tag to make this work is wxTE_PROCESS_TAB. As it was pointed out to me though, this may not be the best solution because tabs are invisible characters. Thanks for your input @VZ.